# MySQL parallel column names

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database(MyISAM & InnoDB) with decent structure but the table/column naming standard is really really bad(mixed languages and naming styles).

The backend code(and SQL queries) has to be replaced in phases. So, I'm looking for the best method to make sure `table1.cheese_is_jummy` and `table2.cheese` "points at" the same data (for read/write).

1. Is there some way to use multiple identifiers for the same column?
2. If not, is there a method to clone data on UPDATE/INSERT?

Example -

```
UPDATE table1
SET cheese_is_jummy = 1
WHERE id = 1
```

triggers  an

```
UPDATE table2
SET cheese = 1
WHERE id = 1
```

and vice versa

Comment: If I understood your problem correctly, foreign key constraints and the ON UPDATE subclause (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) would have the desire effect. This of course would require altering the database structure.

Comment: Have you thought about using views?

Comment: Thanks. Both suggestions seems to solve my problem but views seems simpler to use.